# Is there any possible ways to get args from RejectedExecutionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor, spring-aop

here I have a question.

I'm overwriting my thread pool's `RejectedExecutionHandler`, I want to deal with the exceeding threads which were too many for the thread pool and will be ignored by discard policy, then printing logs to show which of the thread is discarded.

I have solved how to get it done when using Explicit call like `executor.submit(runnable)`

But when dealing with methods annotated with`@Async`, it seems impossible to achieve the args though I can see them in task's arg2 like this:
[image]

So far I have no idea how to get these 2 args, and once the threads is too many to my thread pool, I have no idea to check which thread with which parameters was discarded by

I can only get a thread id and thread name ... and that's not I want.

healp me please! thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always post example code in code blocks, no screenshots. The latter are OK for _additionally_ illustrating specific problems in an IDE or for providing additional detail. But nobody can copy & paste the code from your screenshot in order to reproduce your problem. Furthermore, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just snippets. The easier the problem can be reproduced, the more likely are you to receive a helpful answer. Thank you.

Comment: @kriegaex thank you so much for your tips. next time I will not make the same mistake like this. So far I have solved my problem. The solution was in my own answer showing below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for @kriegaex's tips!

So far I Have Solved this problem.

[Here](https://github.com/WilliamChen-luckbob/LearningDEMO/tree/master/GracefulThreadPool) is my solution in github of how to customize a `RejectedExecutionHandler` and print the key logs of the tasks which were discarded by the already full thread pool.

So far, it supports `@Async`, normal `Runnable` and `Callable`, and customized tasks implements my customized interface `IRejectFreeExecutable`, and also `Runnable` and `Callable` invoked in anonymous ways.

the test code is in `AsyncController`

I have not consider the situations if `Runnable` or `Callable` was wrapped by `FutureTask` or something else.

I think that problem can be solved based on these existing solution.